# How do I stop msbuild from missing out files when doing a web publish?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, visual-studio-2013

I have a solution with several projects in it with dependencies.
When I build the web site project, the bin folder contains a number of sub folders
Some from AjaxControlToolkit.dll, some from folders generated by dependency projects.
I also get the PDB files generated and copied into the bin folder.

Everything works

If I do a publish using the context menu (publish to file system)
I get the same files generated
Everything works

When I do a web publish using msbuild
I do NOT get the PDB files for the dependencies (but do for the web site)
I do NOT get the folders copied into the bin folder

This breaks a lot of stuff.

I do the MSBuild in 2 steps
1 -> compile in source directory
At this point, all files and folders are present in the source bin folder
2 -> publish to a new folder
At this point the dependent files and folders are not transferred across.

From further investigation:

obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin in the project does NOT contain the files

obj\Release\CustomerPortal.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt DOES list the files

Batch File

```
SET MSBuild="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe"
SET targetFolder=C:\Temp\Customer_Build
SET configuration=Release


%MSBUILD% "%targetBuildFolder%\Customer.CustomerPortal.sln" /t:Build /p:Configuration=%configuration%;BuildProjectReferences=true;Platform="Any CPU" >> "%targetFolder%\build_all.log"


%MSBUILD% "%targetBuildFolder%\CustomerPortal\CustomerPortal.csproj" /t:WebPublish /p:PublishUrl=%targetBuildFolder%\_B_MyCustomer\;VisualStudioVersion=11.0;WebPublishMethod=FileSystem;Configuration=%configuration%;BuildProjectReferences=true;DeployOnBuild=True;PackageAsSingleFile=False;PrecompileBeforePublish=False;ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol=False;Platform="AnyCPU" >> "%targetFolder%\build_all.log"
```

Publish Profile XML

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Debug</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>True</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>C:\Temp\Customer_Build\Deploy\MyCustomer</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Does anyone know a way that I can either:
1.  Specify a command line option that will allow the same behaviour for MSBUILD as the profile does
or
2.  Use the profile, but be able to override the publish folder and configuration

Comment: I had a similar issue today. We are publishing a web site project to a local folder and then package it using a Wix installer project. We wanted to keep the pdb to enable remote debugging scenarios. In the end, we added a copy task in the project to move the pdb from the bin folder to the publish target folder before packaging the installer.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the problem was?  I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  I just started adding copy steps into the batch file I am using